# Control to display NSURL as small icons and names in a row

Tags: macos, cocoa

How can I display a URL such as `file://localhost/Users/xxxx/Desktop/Pictures` as shown in the picture below?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That there is an [`NSPathControl`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSPathControl_class/Reference/Reference.html%23//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSPathControl).